# select series based on index in a DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.Series` like

```
myS = pd.Series(np.arange(1,11,1))
```

I also have a `pd.DataFrame` like

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[7,8,9]])
```

I would like to select values in `myS` based on index in `mydf`, but would like to have the results stored in a dataframe with same shape as `mydf`.

So the desired resulting dataframe is `pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[8,9,1]])`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
yourdf=mydf.replace(myS)
yourdf
Out[174]: 
   0  1   2
0  2  3   4
1  8  9  10
```